# How to return a JsonResult or an ActionResult in the same method depending on input?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, model-view-controller, jsonresult

I have a situation where i need return a JSONResult or a Redirect.
Is it possible?

Example:

```
public ActionResult Example(string code)
{
  if(string.IsNullorEmpty(code))
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  else
    return Json(new { success = true, message= "Next step"});
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to return both since they are `ActionResults`. But if you return a `RedirectToAction` inside an Ajax Call, it won't redirect. Is that your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. In fact, the code you posted is exactly how you do it!

[`Controller.RedirectToAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.String%29) returns a [`RedirectToRouteResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirecttorouteresult(v=vs.118).aspx), [`Controller.Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json%28System.Object%29) returns a [`JsonResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx). They both inherit from [`ActionResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx), so returning them as an [`ActionResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) will work just fine.

---

**If you're working with AJAX:**

Even though you didn't say what your calling context was, as mentioned by an [insightful comment by Thiago Ferreira](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017452/how-i-do-when-i-can-return-a-jsonresult-and-an-actionresult-in-the-same-method/36017655#comment59686426_36017452), redirects don't work with AJAX.
You need to return an error message, then handle it on the client side.

For example on your action method:

```
public ActionResult Example(string code)
{
    if(string.IsNullorEmpty(code))
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
        string actionUrl = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home");
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Code not provided", redirectTo = actionUrl});
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { success = true, message= "Next step"});
    }
}
```

Handling it on the client side:

```
if(response.success) {
    // yay
} else if(response.redirectTo) {
    window.location.href = response.redirectTo;
}
```

Comment: This method is probably preferred, but you *could* return either a JsonResult or a RedirectToAction. Though you'd have to have the success/fail/done functions of your Ajax call be able to check if the response is a returned view vs a json object. Otherwise the callbacks won't know whether to render the content, which DOM element to insert it under, or if they should just do some logic based off the Json.

Comment: But in which condition we can use both in single method? In fact is it?